# Multiple bot text responds with python/flask/jquery

Tags: python, jquery

I have my chat app with simple ask/respond paragraphs. How can I write multiple bot returns ? Now it returns only 1 line: "Hello! I am Vic"

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    u = request.args.get('msg')
    #return str(english_bot.get_response(userText))
    if  "hello" in str(u):
        time.sleep(randint(1,5))
        b = str("Hello! I am Vic")
        return b
        time.sleep(randint(1,5))
        return "How can I help you?"
```

jquery code:

```js
function getBotResponse() {
    var rawText = $("#textInput").val();
    var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p>';
    $("#textInput").val("");
    $("#chatbox").append(userHtml);
    document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});

    $('#chatbox').animate({scrollTop: $('#chatbox').prop("scrollHeight")});

    $.get("/get", { msg: rawText }).done(function(data) {
      var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
      $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
      document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
      $('#chatbox').animate({scrollTop: $('#chatbox').prop("scrollHeight")});
    });
  }
getBotResponse();
$("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        getBotResponse();
        var scroll=$('#chatbox');
        scroll.animate({scrollTop: scroll.prop("scrollHeight")});
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">

<p class="botText"><span>Hello</span></p>
</div>
<div id="userInput">
<input id="textInput" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Message..." autofocus>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use :
-markov chains is an algorithm that is used by google at google assistant
-you can try to use deep learning ,tensorflow and with recurrent neural network you can try to build a model
-you can try to make an array with question to ask an potential responses and then to look if the question is equal with a part of response
-in python are different library that are really easy  to use to build chatbots you can search for one
-or you can try from the client side with JavaScript

Anyway but all this must to use sockets for real time comunication